# Faster ByteString construction tips

Tags: c, performance, haskell, bytestring

I am new to Haskell, and I've stuck with efficiency issues..

Task is: Build CSV file from 4GB text file where columns have constant size

column sizes are known, for example [col1: 4 chars wide, col2: 2 chars wide, etc...
file can only contain [A-Z0-9] ASCII chars so there is no point in escaping cells

```
I have: 

$ cat example.txt 
AAAABBCCCC...
AAA1B1CCC1...
... (72 chars per line, usually 50 mln lines)


I need: 
$ cat done.csv
AAAA,BB,CCCC, ...
AAA1,B1,CCC1, ...
...
```

this is my fastest code in Haskell,
takes about 2 minutes to process entire 4GB file.
I need at maximum 30 seconds

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Unsafe as U
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Builder
import Data.Monoid
import Data.List

col_sizes = intercalate [1] $ map (`replicate` 0) cs
  where
    cs = [4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 10, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 10]

sp = char8 ',' -- column separator
nl = char8 '\n'

separator !cs !cl !xs !xl !ci !xi
  | c  == 1   = ps
  | xi == xl  = mempty -- at the end of bytestring, end recursion
  | cl == ci  = pr
  | otherwise = pc
  where
    c  = U.unsafeIndex cs ci         -- get column separation indicator
    w  = word8 . U.unsafeIndex xs    -- get char from BS at position
    p  = separator cs cl xs xl       -- partial recursion call
    pr = nl   <> p  0       (xi + 1) -- end of row, put '\n', reset counter, recur
    ps = sp   <> p (ci + 1)  xi      -- end of column, put column separator, recur
    pc = w xi <> p (ci + 1) (xi + 1) -- in the middle of column, copy byte, recur


main = do
  contents <- B.getContents
  BL.putStr . toLazyByteString $ init_sep sp_after_char contents


init_sep cs xs = separator cs (l cs) xs (l xs) 0 0
  where l = fromIntegral . B.length

sp_after_char = B.pack col_sizes
```

And this is my implementation in C http://pastebin.com/Kjz3Mugs 
(to long to paste it here...) 
takes about 5 seconds to process the same file

So my Haskell code is approx. 20x slower. 
Because Haskell ByteString filter and map are faster than my implementations in C,
(both take less than 2s to process same file doing some simple modifications) 
I hope there is something wrong in my Haskell code and I won't be forced to use C.

### UPDATE: test data generator is available here http://pastebin.com/aJ3RW3jG

#### On production, data is piped from one binary to other so there is no hard drive IO

#### to test solutions I used SSD drive but I think that Ext4 cached that file anyway in RAM

```
time cat test.txt > /dev/null
cat test.txt > /dev/null  0,00s user 0,35s system 99% cpu 0,353 total
```

Vanilla generator:

```
time ./data_builder | head -50000000 > /dev/null
./data_builder  0,02s user 1,09s system 30% cpu 3,709 total
head -50000000 > /dev/null  2,95s user 0,76s system 99% cpu 3,708 total
```

#### my C solution:

```
time ./tocsvc < test.txt > /dev/null 
./tocsvc < test.txt > /dev/null  5,35s user 0,35s system 100% cpu 5,689 total
```

with generator

```
time ./data_builder | head -50000000 | ./tocsvc > /dev/null
./data_builder  0,02s user 1,18s system 18% cpu 6,460 total
head -50000000  3,15s user 1,19s system 67% cpu 6,459 total
./tocsvc > /dev/null  5,81s user 0,55s system 98% cpu 6,459 total
```

#### @GabrielGonzalez Haskell solution

```
time ./tocsvh1 < test.txt > /dev/null 
./tocsv < test.txt > /dev/null  19,56s user 0,41s system 100% cpu 19,950 total
```

with generator

```
time ./data_builder | head -50000000 | ./tocsvh1 > /dev/null 
./data_builder  0,11s user 3,04s system 7% cpu 41,320 total
head -50000000  7,29s user 3,56s system 26% cpu 41,319 total
./tocsvh2 > /dev/null  33,01s user 2,42s system 85% cpu 41,327 total
```

#### my Haskell solution

```
time ./tocsvh2 < test.txt > /dev/null 
./tocsvh2 < test.txt > /dev/null  128,63s user 2,95s system 100% cpu 2:11,45 total
```

with generator

```
time ./data_builder | head -50000000 | ./tocsvh2 > /dev/null 
./data_builder  0,02s user 1,26s system 28% cpu 4,526 total
head -50000000  3,17s user 1,33s system 99% cpu 4,524 total
./tocsvh2 > /dev/null  129,95s user 3,33s system 98% cpu 2:14,75 total
```

#### @LukeTaylor solution

```
time ./tocsvh3 < test.txt > /dev/null 
./tocsv < test.txt > /dev/null  324,38s user 4,13s system 100% cpu 5:28,18 total
```

with generator

```
time ./data_builder | head -50000000 | ./tocsvh3 > /dev/null 
./data_builder  0,43s user 4,46s system 1% cpu 5:30,34 total
head -50000000  5,20s user 2,82s system 2% cpu 5:30,34 total
./tocsv > /dev/null  329,08s user 4,21s system 100% cpu 5:32,96 total
```

Comment: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/profiling-and-optimization.html

Comment: @TheInternet already read and applied, and this is what I ended up with. Could You point to any particular fragment of this chapter that I should consider again?

Comment: Please provide test data so that we can benchmark our solutions against your C code before we submit an answer.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez I think you can build suitable test data from the code - 50 million lines, each 72 chars in length, split according to the values in the `cs` array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get within a factor of 3 of C just by using raw pointer operations:

```
import Control.Monad (unless, when, void)
import Foreign.Safe hiding (void)
import System.IO
import Foreign.C.Types

bufInSize :: Int
bufInSize = n * (1024 * 1024 `div` n) where n = sum sizes0 + 1

bufOutSize :: Int
bufOutSize = n * (1024 * 1024 `div` n) where n = sum sizes0 + length sizes0

sizes0 :: [Int]
sizes0 = [4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 10, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 10]

-- I also tried using the C memset using the FFI, but got the same speed
memcpy :: Ptr Word8 -> Ptr Word8 -> Int -> IO ()
memcpy dst src n = when (n > 0) $ do
    x <- peek src
    poke dst x
    memcpy (dst `plusPtr` 1) (src `plusPtr` 1) (n - 1)

main = do
    allocaArray bufInSize  $ \bufIn0  -> do
    allocaArray bufOutSize $ \bufOut0 -> do
    with (44 :: Word8)  $ \cm -> do
        let loop bufIn bufOut sizes suffixIn suffixOut = do
                let (bytesIn, bytesOut, sizes', copy) = case sizes of
                        []     -> (1, 1    , sizes0,    memcpy bufOut bufIn 1)
                        [s]    -> (s, s    , []    ,    memcpy bufOut bufIn s)
                        s:izes -> (s, s + 1, izes  , do
                            memcpy  bufOut              bufIn s
                            memcpy (bufOut `plusPtr` s) cm    1 )

                if suffixIn < bytesIn
                then do
                    eof <- hIsEOF stdin
                    if eof
                        then hPutBuf stdout bufOut0 (bufOut `minusPtr` bufOut0)
                        else do
                            suffixIn' <- hGetBuf stdin bufIn0 bufInSize
                            loop bufIn0 bufOut sizes suffixIn' suffixOut
                else if suffixOut < bytesOut
                then do
                    hPutBuf stdout bufOut0 (bufOut `minusPtr` bufOut0)
                    loop bufIn bufOut0 sizes suffixIn bufOutSize
                else do
                    copy
                    loop (bufIn  `plusPtr` bytesIn )
                         (bufOut `plusPtr` bytesOut)
                         sizes'
                         (suffixIn  - bytesIn )
                         (suffixOut - bytesOut)
        loop bufIn0 bufOut0 sizes0 0 bufOutSize
```

Here are some rough `time`-based measurements using an input file of 1000000 lines:

```
$ # The C Version
$ time ./a.out < in.dat > out.dat

real    0m0.189s
user    0m0.116s
sys 0m0.068s
$ # The Haskell version
$ time ./csv < in.dat > out2.dat

real    0m0.536s
user    0m0.428s
sys 0m0.104s
$ diff out.dat out2.dat
$ # No difference
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some alternative code to process a file line by line (since `ByteString` supports that itself), and that seems to work ok:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B
import Data.Int (Int64)

main = do
    contents <- B.getContents
    mapM B.putStrLn (process contents)

process :: B.ByteString -> [B.ByteString]
process bs = do
    line <- B.lines bs
    return $ B.intercalate "," $ splitLine line indices

splitLine :: B.ByteString -> [Int64] -> [B.ByteString]
splitLine l []      = [l] 
splitLine l (i:is)  = let (head, tail) = B.splitAt i l 
                      in  head : splitLine tail is

indices = [1,2,3] :: [Int64]
```

If I create a file containing 500000 copies of the string "1223334444" then it runs in a second or so:

```
 $ time ./blines < blah.txt > blah2.txt

 real   0m1.280s
 user   0m1.192s
 sys    0m0.080s
```

Does that match what you're trying to achieve?

Update: This is still quite slow with large amounts of data. With 8 million lines, it takes about 15secs.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tried this approach, it takes 5 minutes to process the data. Interesting is that this code has similar time of execution when You operate on normal Haskell strings and use getLine and putStrLn.

Comment: I guess one problem is the `splitAt` is making unnecessary copies each time and gets more wastful the more columns you have. Building the columns in one go would be better, but I'm not sure how to do that yet :).

Comment: theoretically splitAt, tail, etc. from ByteString and ByteString.Lazy have to produce huge overhead for gathering data form ByteString. B.unsafeIndex is fastest I found. Only thing that comes to my mind and is not FFI to C, is to look under the hood of B.map or B.filter and use some of the internals (which are unfortunately hidden)

Comment: @KonradKuźnicki The `ByteString` internals are *not* hidden, specifically to allow creating your own high-performance functions using them. However, the haddock pages for the `.Internal` modules aren't built on hackage, probably related to safe haskell somehow.

Comment: Try `mapM_` instead of `mapM`